# Taillwind CSS configuration not working with React

Tags: html, reactjs, tailwind-css

Tailwind CSS is not working for me. I've updated to the latest version, and Tailwind is the only thing that's failing with no error in the console.

My header component and file tree: https://i.stack.imgur.com/e3brX.png

**tailwind.config.js**

```js
module.exports = {
  mode: "jit",
  purge: [
    "./src/pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    "./src/components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
  ],
  darkMode: false, // or 'media' or 'class'
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        amazon_blue: {
          light: "#232F3E",
          DEFAULT: "#131921",
        },
      },
    },
  },
  variants: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [require("@tailwindcss/line-clamp")],
};
```

**My CSS file**

```css
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

my git hub-https://github.com/Shadow2389/amazon-duplicate

Comment: Please post code instead of images, and describe what part is not working and in what way. What were you expecting, and what are you getting instead.

Comment: done please check it know

Comment: What's the path to your CSS file and where are you importing it?

Comment: D:\Amazon-starter-template-nextjs\src\styles\globals.css

Comment: i am importing using tailwind i think

Answer (score 0):

I found out solution. Your`tailwind.config.js` is still old version. Update as,

```
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        amazon_blue: {
          light: "#232F3E",
          DEFAULT: "#131921",
        },
      },
    },
  },
  variants: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [require("@tailwindcss/line-clamp")],
}
```

Comment: thanks very much it worked . do I also need a output.css